# How to define an array with conditional elements in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I actually have no idea about this one :O

### JS - Valid

```
 interface Claim {
  tractableClaimId: string;
  clientClaimId: string;
  accidentId: string;
  clientId: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  dateOfAccident: Date;
  policyHolderSessionId: string;
  status: string;
  actions: string;
  estimate?: Estimate;
}

const [claims, setClaims] = useState<Claim[]>([]);

const claims = ['jamie']
const isSearchOrFilter = true;

[
   ...(isSearchOrFilter ? claims : []),
   ...['hutber']
]
//Output: (2) ["jamie", "hutber"]
```

### Ts Error

```
Type 'false | Claim[]' is not an array type.  TS2461

    67 |     });
    68 |     setClaims([
  > 69 |       ...(isSearchOrFilter ? claims : []),
       |          ^
    70 |       ...['hutber']
    71 |     ]);
```

Comment: should it not be `useState<string[]>([])`? you are not settingt objects with the right interface definition

Comment: Ah I see... its because `[]` inside my conditional are not typed as Claim...